# See deleted files between two git branches of specific file type

Tags: git, diff, delete-file, git-diff

I would like to see the name of all deleted `.scss` files in a release branch `release/1.0` compared to master branch `master`.

I tried

```
git checkout release/1.0
git diff --name-only master
```

But i can see other files than `.scss` and i can not see if the file is deleted, added or modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) to filter out other changes (additions, modifications, etc), then use the [`[--] <path>` construct](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203) (here in your case, `-- *.<ext>`) to limit to these file types

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D master release/1.0 -- *.scss
```

Edited: thanks to [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) for the interesting back-and-forth in the comments about the refs.

Comment: @LeGEC I agree, this is a bit unclear, I'm unsatisfied with the current formulation. Let me see. I might just have gone with my first idea, following what OP described, should be `master..release/1.0`

Comment: Thanks ! I ended up copying my comment in a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

RomainValeri suggested in his answer a direct solution to your question:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D master release/1.0 -- *.scss
```

---

Some other variants which may be of interest :

- use `--name-status` rather than `--name-only` :

```
git diff --name-status master release/1.0 -- *.scss
```

- use the [3 dots notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1) for git diff to view the modifications that happened on one side only of the branches :

```
# modifications that were brought in by release/1.0:
git diff --name-status master...release/1.0

# modifications that were brought in by master:
git diff --name-status release/1.0...master
```

This would give the same list of files as the one you would see in a merge request.